# Clickhouse SQL query that returns the average of a value but trims top and bottom 5%

Tags: sql, average, clickhouse, quantile

I am working with ClickHouse and I have a requirement to calculate the average of a specific value from a table, but I need to exclude the top and bottom 5% of values. I have tried using the quantile function to calculate the percentiles and then applying filters, but it involves selecting from the table multiple times. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this in a single query without redundant selections?

this query works:
`q = "SELECT avg(x) FROM table  WHERE x <= (SELECT quantile(0.95)(x) FROM table)  AND x >= (SELECT quantile(0.05)(x) FROM table)"`

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/top-n-and-remain/

Answer (score 1):

Using window functions:

```
SELECT avgIf(x, x BETWEEN low AND high) FROM
(
    WITH ResolutionWidth AS x, quantiles(0.1, 0.9)(x) OVER () AS q
    SELECT x, q[1] AS low, q[2] AS high FROM hits
)
```